# Word representing the "giving up" or "relinquishing" of control for part of a process

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Is there a word that defines the act of giving up control of part of a process to a separate entity.

For example, in a website you can often use Google or Facebook to log in.  Or a website might use PayPal to manage the financial checkout process.

The word that springs to mind is 'syndicate', is this correct use of the word?

e.g. "You can use Paypal to syndicate payment processing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word that comes to mind is **delegate** (to entrust to another or to assign responsibility or authority)

You can delegate payment processing to Paypal.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delegate

There's a subtle difference.  "Giving up" or "relinquishing" has a connotation that someone else is responsible for taking it from you and you acquiesce.  "Delegate" has the connotation that you are the one responsible.

---

Another is **farm out** (to turn over (as a job) for performance by another usually under contract)

You can farm out payment processing to Paypal.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farm%20out

---

Another is **outsource** (to procure needed services under contract from an outside supplier)

You can outsource payment processing to Paypal.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outsource